# CNG station type not available in google places API,gas _station include both cng and petrol pumps, i want only cng station

Tags: android

nearby places API have types for particular things. gas_station type include both cng stations and petrol pumps in places API in android, i want only CNG station how can i get it? is there any sub ID for cng stations?

API have predefined types can they b customized by our requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API, you can now search the following places nearby.
kindly read the document from here  [Official docs](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)
hope this helps you